# Difference between h'' and D[h[t],t,t]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

In the output of the following code block, simplification of h''[t] produces the same result as D[h[t],t,t]. But the form produced by h''[t] has a removable singularity that causes trouble (division by zero) if not removed. Is this output to be expected? Is there a bug in the code block? Or, is this a bug in Mathematica?

```
    ClearAll[n, x, sCheb]
    sCheb[n_, x_] := ChebyshevT[n, 2 x - 1]
    test[hlist_List /; AllTrue[hlist, NumericQ]] := Block[{n, i},
       n = Length[hlist];
       h = Function[t, Sum[hlist[[i]] sCheb[i, t], {i, 1, n}]]; 
       Print[h[t]]; Print[h'[t]]; Print[h''[t]]; Print[D[h[t], t, t]]
       ]
    test[{0, 1}]
```

```
-1+2 (-1+2 t)^2

 8 (-1+2 t)

 (8 (-2+2 (-1+2 t)^2))/(-1+(-1+2 t)^2)

 16
```

Comment: `Print[h''[t] // Simplify]` will give the same result as `Print[D[h[t], t, t]`. In one case the simplification occurs automatically, in the other it doesn't.

Comment: `Print[h''[t] // Trace]` reveals what happens under the hood. Basically `h` is differentiated symbolically (with arbitrary arguments, not `n = 2`; and that in turn leads to `sCheb`, `ChebyshevT` and then `ChebyshevU` being differentiated according to [standard rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Differentiation_and_integration), before specializing to `n=2`, and `i = 1, 2`. As @Bob points out, there is some simplification to be done that *Mma* won't do automatically.